# How to save a Firestore number into a variable in flutter?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Right now I have a Firestore folder which contains numbered documents with information like Volume, temperature, air quality. These values are saved as numbers. I somehow want these Firestore numbers to be saved as Integer variables in my flutter project, so that I can work with them (For example show dark colors if the Volume is too loud).

But it just doesn't work, no matter what I try. Is it even possible? I can only display the firestore values, but I can't save them..

Here a picture of my database:
[image]

My code:

```
  Future<String> getValue() async{
    final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Digitaluhr')
        .doc('1.002')
        .get();
        
    Future <String> lautstaerke = doc['Lautstärke'];
    return lautstaerke;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future <String> Lautstaerke = getValue();
    String transform = Lautstaerke.toString();
    var test = int.parse(transform);
    assert(test is int);

Text('$test'),
```

Output:
[image]

Please help :(

Comment: Since `getValue` is a `Future`, you have to use `async/await` to get its value. If you need this in a build method, `FutureBuilder` can solve your problem.

Comment: Hello @LeonBrey, any progress? Please consider [accepting and upvoting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped you. Thanks

Comment: Hello, thank you, but my intention is not the "get" the value by displaying it, my intention is to store the Firestore number into an integer, with which I can then work with. (For example with if commands)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getValue(),
    builder: (_, snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        var test = int.parse(snapshot.data);
        ...
      }
      return Container();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: It doesnt know "value".

Comment: Hey @LeonBrey...Use snapshot.data sorry - I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But it then still simply returns the Container (Error).

Comment: Is something wrong with my method maybe?

Comment: Do you want it to show the text?

Comment: Basically I want to store the Firestore number into an Integer, and then work with it.

Comment: So if the Firestore number is 3, I want an Integer that reads it and than has the value 3. I need this for several if commands :(

Comment: @LeonBrey This answer shows a good example of `FutureBuilder` usage and it should work. If you get an error, please share the whole message. Perhaps we can see what exactly was done wrong  and fix it

Comment: All I had to do was: Luftguete = snapshot.data.docs[itemCount]
                                  ['Luftgüte']; This whole Future stuff and the method was crap. But still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Posting LeonBrey's solution for visibility.

The problem was fixed with the following:

```
Luftguete = snapshot.data.docs[itemCount] ['Luftgüte'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is  `doc['Lautstärke']` return string, while your variable data type is `Future<String>`

```dart
Future <String> lautstaerke = doc['Lautstärke'];
```

Try changing like below

```dart
String lautstaerke = doc['Lautstärke'];
```